# Does using constraint layout and 'dp' for height/width/margin etc ensure responsiveness of app?

Tags: android, responsive-design, size, pixel

I am designing the layouts for my Android app, and trying to replicate the layout as designed by the graphic designer. To ensure that my layout is very close to the design designed by the graphic designer, I had to hard code the height/width/margins etc with 'dp' as unit, instead of match_parent/wrap_content etc.
Also, I'm using constraint layout as my parent layout.
Will this guarantee responsiveness of my app, that is will it adjust to varying screen sizes/densities?

If not, what do I have to do to ensure responsiveness of my app?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, it won't. Setting hardcoded height and width won't do it. What you can do is create multiple layout XMLs for specific screen sizes, resolution, or don't put hardcoded height and width use guidelines and margins instead.

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun, isn't dp (density independent pixel), supposed to make the layout 'independent' of screen density? If not, why was 'dp' created in first place as an alternative to 'px'?

Comment: Yes, it supposed to do it by itself and it does it but sometimes it looks horrible and you should check your app in different screen sizes to make sure it's looking the way it should be.

Comment: Hardcoded heights are also a nightmare if they contain text from a usability standpoint. Make sure that you check how readable the content is on small devices with a big font-size in the user settings (due to bad vision). Often times, texts will not fit and the apps get less usable.